# how to handle spaces in the filepath

Tags: openfiledialog

So, i wrote a code, that would compile a C++ code using tdm gcc compiler. My code uses `openfiledialog` to allow the user to choose the file to be compiled and then I construct a String command as,

```
cmd = "/c g++ " + openfiledialog.filename.toString() + " -o temp.exe";
```

And then i'm executing this command in a normal way using process instance. But, if there are spaces in filepath, eg: "D:\haha haha\test.cpp" then the g++ compiler shows an error saying no such directory haha etc etc. how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need quotes around the file name to form the `g++` command line:

```
cmd = "/c g++ \"" + openfiledialog.filename.toString() + "\" -o temp.exe";
```

Alternatively, you could post-process the value returned by `.toString()` to insert an escape (backslash `\`) character before each space. But the quote method is easier.

Comment: @VishalSharma yes you could also use a `.format` but it's unnecessary for this simple case. And you'd still need to include escaped quotes in the string.